# my opencart website was working fine then im getting this error when i try to add product

Tags: php, opencart

this is the error im getting .. and i have checked with ftp there is really no file name "gen_TDKT.php" what should i do

Warning: include_once(/home/govacpk/public_html/luxurina/system/config/ssb_library/admin/generators/gen_TDKT.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/govacpk/public_html/luxurina/system/config/ssb_library/ssb_autogen.php on line 1Warning: include_once(): Failed opening '/home/govacpk/public_html/luxurina/system/config/ssb_library/admin/generators/gen_TDKT.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/opt/alt/php56/usr/share/pear:/opt/alt/php56/usr/share/php') in /home/govacpk/public_html/luxurina/system/config/ssb_library/ssb_autogen.php on line 1

Comment: Are you able to find Which Extension uses ssb_library? It is not default Opencart Library. Which version of Opencart you are using ?

Comment: no i dont know which module uses ssb_library and im using opencart 1.5

Comment: how do i figure out which module uses ssb_library?

Comment: If you have a test instance, then try clearing and refreshing the modification. Please be aware any hard coded Line Of Codes will Be Removed. So Don't Refresh it in Live Server Rather take a backup and try clearing the modification. 

It may work.

Comment: okay ill try it thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

ok so i found backup of my website .. there was this file gen_TDKT.php, copied it to host now everything works.

Comment: Glad to hear that you found out the solution.